# Android: Remove white background behind button when using elevation

Tags: android

I have a little problem when I add some elevation to a button or imagebutton. If I add elevation to a button I see a small white background behind it and If I add it to an imagebutton I see like a small white padding around it. Anyone knows how can I get rit of them?.

This is the code for the button:

```html
<Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceLarge"
        android:elevation="20dp"
        android:stateListAnimator="@anim/button_elevation"
        android:text="Boton con elevacion"
        />
```

This is the button_elevation file:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_enabled="true"
        android:state_pressed="true">
        <objectAnimator
            android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
            android:propertyName="translationZ"
            android:valueFrom="2dip"
            android:valueTo="4dip"
            android:valueType="floatType" />
    </item>
    <item>
        <objectAnimator
            android:duration="@android:integer/config_shortAnimTime"
            android:propertyName="translationZ"
            android:valueFrom="4dip"
            android:valueTo="2dip"
            android:valueType="floatType" />
    </item>
</set>
```

This is the code for the imagebutton:

```html
<ImageButton
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/imageButton"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="@drawable/button_selector"
        android:elevation="30dp"
        />
```

And this is the button_selector file:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:state_pressed="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/botoniniciob2"/>
    <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/botoninicion2"/>
</selector>
```

I'm using Android Studio and the target SDK is API22.

Thanks a lot in advance.